# Why an Integer within the parentheses of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, parentheses

Somewhere I saw a `java.util.List` defined as below.
`List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(0);`
Can anybody explain what the integer in parentheses does and how to use it? Thanks.

Comment: [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter decides the starting capacity of the `ArrayList`.

An `ArrayList` allocates memory internally to hold a certain number of objects. When you add more elements too it, it has to allocate more memory and copy all the data to the new place, which takes some time. Therefor you can specify a guess on how many objects you are going to put in your `ArrayList` to help Java.
A starting size of `0` probably indicates that the programmer thinks the `ArrayList` will seldom be used, so there is no need to allocate memory for it to start with.

**[EDIT]**
To clarify, as @LuiggiMendoza and @emory say in the discussion, it is very hard to think of a scenario where it would make sense to use `0` as initial capacity. In the majority of cases, the default constructor works just fine.

Comment: "A starting size of 0 probably indicates that the programmer thinks the ArrayList will seldom be used" Maybe, maybe not. That depends on the implementation.

Comment: Hi Luiggi, what do you mean by "depends on the implementation". Do you think a programmer can have another reason to define the initial size as zero. Could you please explain?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Depends on the implementation?  The implementation is specified (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html).  The most logical reason to specify a starting size of 0 is to conserve memory, anticipating that it will be empty for a long time.

Comment: @emory Indeed, it could be a very bad case if you know that your array could have thousand of elements, because every time you add a new element, the arraylist must increase (this means: create a new array with a size increased by last array length per a factor, maybe 1.5, then copy all the elements from the old array to the new one, yes pretty heavy when you have lots of data). Also, the default constructor initializes the array with a capacity of 10, based in a further analysis done by the Java language designers. I don't see the good of a 0 initial capacity on performance.

Comment: @emory also that's the OpenJDK implementation, there is a Sun JDK implementation too (and maybe other implementations that I don't know yet).

Comment: An edge case where it might make sense is `void print ( @ NotNullable List<Politician> allHonestPoliticians)`.  Must provide a non null List, but don't anticipate ever using the `add` method.  Add a sanity check `assert 0 == allHonestPoliticians . size ( ) : "BS" ;`

Comment: @emory In cases when you don't know what the initial capacity could be, just use the default constructor, its size will be 0 too.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I recommend using the default constructor, but if I read the OpenJDK implementation correctly, the size of the default constructor will be 10.

Comment: @emory if you have a real case scenario to prove initializing an ArrayList with 0 capacity is better than the Java language designers proposed (10 by default), I'll accept that I'm wrong and you're correct (and don't tell me that a 10 length array has worse performance than a 0 length array, that's just not valid when you have more than 100 MBs RAM available).

Answer (score 2):

To define an initial capacity of the ArrayList.

Comment: I guess this is well defined in the documentation I´ve posted. Maybe OP question is: **why?**

Answer (score 1):

It is to define an initial capacity of the `ArrayList`.

You are not obliged to pass a size parameter if you want because there is a constructor that has no arguments as well.

Whenever you add an additional element, and if the list size doesn't permit for addition, the `List` class will create another `List` in the `Heap` with a larger size and will copy the content of the old `array` to it with the additional element, deleting the old `array`.

The capacity in the initial instantiation is there to create the exact `size` of the `List` which helps in not allocating additional blocks of memory by creating new `Lists`, deleting the old ones and copying the contents at run time, where it helps in performance.

Answer (score 0):

it specifies the capacity of the list

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse with the **size** of the array list and its **capacity**:

- the **size** is the number of elements in the list;
- the **capacity** is how many elements the list can potentially accommodate without reallocating its internal structures.

When you call `new ArrayList<String>(0)`, you are setting the list's initial *capacity*, not its size. In other words, when constructed in this manner, the array list starts its life empty.

Comment: Also, it would be good to add the benefits and pitfalls of initialize the ArrayList with different capacities.

Comment: I could have been but the question is not about "*the benefits and pitfalls of initialize the `ArrayList` with different capacities*".

Comment: Hmm... I get this might be established terminology, but isn't "size" kind of misleading? Wouldn't "fullness", "load", "vacancy" or "saturation" be better?

Answer (score 0):

When used as

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>(5);
```

It Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

By default when nothing is specified.

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>;
```

an empty list with an initial capacity of ten is constructed.

Read [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29)

Do not misundetstand this as size of the ArrayList.